# Seperate one array into two arrays based on the class's values. JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

So I have three classes, `Person`, `GroupOfPeople` and a `Main` class.

Class person:

```
public class Person {
    
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private char gender;
    private double weight;

    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    
    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    
    ... other getters and setters respectively
}
```

As you can see the Person class has an instance variable of gender.
In `GroupOfPeople` I created an array of persons as followed:

```
private Person[] personGroup = new Person[5];
```

This stores all persons, no matter their gender. What I want is a method that separates the men from all the other persons in the array.

Therefore I've created the method `findMen()` that looks like this:

```
public void findMen() {
        int counter = 0;
        Person[] allMen = new Person[5];
        
        while (counter < personGroup.length) {
            if (personGroup[counter].getGender() == 'M') {
                allMen[counter] = personGroup[counter];
            } else {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("All the men are:");
        for (int i = 0; i < allMen.length; i++) {
            if (allMen[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(allMen[i].getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not working, it only adds 1 person to the `allMen` array, while I've defined more men in my main method:

```
GroupOfPeople gop = new GroupOfPeople();
        
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("Person 1");
        p1.setAge(40);
        p1.setGender('M');
        
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setName("Person 2");
        p2.setAge(30);
        p2.setGender('F');
        
        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setName("Person 3");
        p3.setAge(20);
        p3.setGender('M');

        gop.findMen();
```

The output is:

```
All the men are:
Person 1
```

While the expected output is:

```
All the men are:
Person 1
Person 3
```

I hope you can give me some insights as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your `else` body contains a `break`. That means that the loop finishes when a person other than a man is found. You probably want to use `continue` here.

Answer (score 1):

Your break statement is incorrectly placed. it breaks the first time you do not get a man. Break when you have gone over the whole length of the personGroup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.  Get rid of the break;

```
 while (counter < personGroup.length) {
        if (personGroup[counter].getGender() == 'M') {
              allMen[counter] = personGroup[counter];
        } else {
                break;  // get rid of this, you stop if no M is found. 
        }
            counter++;
  }
```

Try it like this

```
while (counter < personGroup.length) {
        if (personGroup[counter].getGender() == 'M') {
              allMen[counter] = personGroup[counter];
        } 
        counter++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought this was the problem, but if I remove it I get a NullPointerException on

if (personGroup[counter].getGender() == 'M') { }

Comment: This is because of ur use of arrays, u have 3 persons defined but the all men is of length 5. U need to use lists instead of the arrays so u can do this with dynamic lengths

Comment: Either use lists (directly allows dynamic sizes of your groupings), or use another index-variable to keep track of at what position to insert the next male person. But then you should first find out how many male person there are to determine the size of the male-array beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The break is causing it to end the loop as soon as you find a female.
The reason you get a NullPointerException when you remove that is because of the use of your arrays

```
ArrayList<Person> allMen = new ArrayList<Person>();
  for(Person p : personGroup){
    if(p.getGender() == 'M') allMen.add(p);
}
```

Finally, to iterate and output men just do the same thing:

```
for(Person p : allMen){
  System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else body contains a `break`. That means that the loop finishes when a person other than a man is found. You probably want to use `continue` here (or drop the `else` entirely).

I have, however, two suggestions:

#### List

Use a `List` instead of an array. A widely-used implementation of the `List` interface is the `ArrayList`. The advantage is that the list is dynamically-sized. That means that you can add an unlimited amount of items to the list without knowning the capacity beforehand.

```java
// Convert the array to a list, if necessary. However, I suggest you replace all arrays
// with lists
List<Person> allPersons = Arrays.asList(personGroup);

List<Person> men = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person p : allPersons) {
    if (p.getGender() == 'M') {
        men.add(p);
    }
}
```

#### Streams

Java 8 was shipped with the Streams API. This could make your code even more concise.

```java
List<Person> men = allPersons.stream() // Stream over all persons
    .filter(p -> p.getGender() == 'M') // Select only men
    .collect(Collectors.toList());     // Put them into a List
```